# Can we use magento luma theme for checkout

Tags: magento2

I'm Using magento 2 and Himarket theme. So the checkout page not working And I changed it to luma theme its work how can i fix the case

This is the error show in the console

```
[2017-12-17 10:00:26] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals" component.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to use two different themes at once on one store view. Looking at the demo for the theme that you posted, it looks like its using default checkout. The styles look mostly the same. So while it's possible the theme is broken, you might also have an issue with your settings for checkout.

If you purchased the theme and it's not working on the store, it's best to contact the theme developer and let them know.